# Clustered Environment: Cannot borrow client for ssl

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I followed the Clustering Topology in the Doc: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile and the Toplogy was done and the ESB Nodes are running correctly. Suppose that my nodes are ***n1.ei.com*** for Node1 and ***n2.ei.com*** for Node2 and ***lb.ei.com*** for LoadBalancing. I want to start the **Analytic Dashboard** on Node1, as a service it started running on https://n1.ei.com:9643/portal but i dont get any data or API to monitor. I followed the wso2carbon.log and found the following error:

> Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client
>   for ssl://${Node1_IP_ADDR}:7712

Noting that my port **Offset is 0**, on Similar questions I found people referring to api-manager.xml file but i dont have these files. I only have **MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml** and **MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml** and I edited them as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventPublisher name="MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher/StatisticsPublisher"
  statistics="disable" trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventpublisher">
  <from streamName="org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="disable" type="wso2event"/>
  <to eventAdapterType="wso2event">
    <property name="username">adminuser</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="password">CIPHERED_TEXT</property>
    <property name="protocol">thrift</property>
    <property name="publishingMode">blocking</property>
    <property name="publishTimeout">0</property>
    <property name="receiverURL">tcp://${Node1_IP_ADDR:7612}</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="password">CIPHERED_TEXT</property>
  </to>
</eventPublisher>
```

Where can i Solve the above error considering my Clustered Environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply but I got it:
as you can see there's a value named statistics here and it was disabled in the question above so I changed it and The Analytic Dashboard now can read data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventPublisher name="MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher/StatisticsPublisher"
  statistics="enable" trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventpublisher">
  <from streamName="org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="disable" type="wso2event"/>
  <to eventAdapterType="wso2event">
    <property name="username">adminuser</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="password">CIPHERED_TEXT</property>
    <property name="protocol">thrift</property>
    <property name="publishingMode">blocking</property>
    <property name="publishTimeout">0</property>
    <property name="receiverURL">tcp://${Node1_IP_ADDR:7612}</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="password">CIPHERED_TEXT</property>
  </to>
</eventPublisher>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your /conf/log4j.properties and check if you have correct informations in the LOGEVENT block :

> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT=org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.LogEventAppender
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.url=tcp://localhost:7611
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%I,%Stacktrace
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.userName=admin
>
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=admin
>
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.processingLimit=1000
> log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.maxTolerableConsecutiveFailure=20